# How to  cache (select_related) relative models which are unique depending on an argument?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like a simple thing:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    "
    month field is enforced to first day of month, so I
    can have an entry by user and by month only.
    "
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    month = models.DateField()
    field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_ok = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    other_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "month"),)
```

So I would like to preload for a given month (as select_related would do) my entries for a user queryset.

```
# at the end it may for exemple be something like that....
user_with_related = User.a_related_manager.get_with_my_model_for_date(my_date)
for u in user_with_related:
    if not u.current_my_model:
        MyModel.create_for_user(u)
    elif not u.current_my_model.is_ok:
        u.current_my_model.rebuild()
 return render(request, "my_template.html", {"users": user_with_related})
```

Not every user have linked MyModel insrance for given month.

Any tip?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear - do you mean that if you have a queryset of contrib.auth.models.User you would like to preload the related MyModel objects? And you would like to limit the preloaded objects to those with a specific month?

Comment: exactly, if this is unclear, I had it at the end.

Comment: well for the example you've given at the end you're querying by date so it doesn't make sense to query User - it makes more sense to do this: `my_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(month=my_date)` and extract User instances from that. Have you got an example that shows a need for more sophisticated behavious in the manager?

Comment: In fact, some user don't have linked `MyModel` and I want a user result in those cases.

Comment: I'm still having difficulty seeing the result you are trying to get. Can you post some examples of the queries you would like to be able to make, showing the paramaters you would pass in and explaining what you would like to be returned.

Comment: in fact, I have a query set of users. I would like a way to get every related MyModels for the given month and add it as a field on each users instances (like `current_my_model`). It's doable in SQL easily but I don't see how to do it with django's ORM.

Comment: give an example of the queries you'd like to be able to do please

Comment: I completed my exemple to give something more concrete. In fact I 'im looking for a left outer join.